# Как сделать такой стиль вкладок?

Tags: css, css3, вкладки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня так реализовано:

```js
<template>
  <nav id="tabs"> 
      <ul>        
        <li :class="{'active':activetab=='cli'}" @click="$emit('seltab','cli')"><span class='s1'>Клиент</span></li>
        <li :class="{'active':activetab=='fin'}" @click="$emit('seltab','fin')"><span class='s2'>Финансовое состояние</span></li>
      </ul> 
  </nav>
    
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props:['activetab'],
  name: 'tabs',
  data () {
    return {
     
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
/*
.tab-wrapper{
  ul{
    border: 1px solid black; 
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 277px;
  }
  li{

    
    padding: 10px;
    
    &:hover{
      cursor:pointer;
      background: #ffffff;
    }
  &.active {background: }
  
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 30px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  }
}

*/
#tabs {
    color:#000000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline;
  ul{
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
  }
  li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:-10px;
    &:hover {cursor:pointer;}
    &.active{ border-bottom:1px solid #fff; }
    &.active span { background:#169BD5; }
    &.active span:before{  z-index: 1; }/* overlap prev element */
    &.active span:after{   border-bottom:1px solid #fff;}
    span {
      position: relative;
      display:inline-block;
      margin:0 9px;
      padding:8px 11px; 
      border-radius:0px 0px 0 0; /* just to smooth the top edges */
      &.s2:before,
      &:after {
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        width: 23px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: inherit; 
      }
      &.s2:before {
        border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
        transform: skew(33deg); 
        left: -13px; /* play with this one to give the LI border ~2px extrusion */
      }
      &.s1:after{
        border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
        transform: skew(33deg);
        right: -13px; /* play with this one to give the LI border ~2px extrusion */
        z-index: 1; /* overlap next element */
      }
    }
  }
} 
 
   
 

</style>
```

Comment: http://pcvector.net/scripts/tabs/191-vkladki-so-skoshennymi-uglami.html
   ,
https://jsbin.com/fotupey/edit?html,css,output   ,   

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655749/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

Comment: HamSter, БЛАГОдарю! Поставил в продакшн твой вариант);

Comment: =>см скрин:
https://pp.userapi.com/c844320/v844320586/11183a/QaBwYJ6kl7E.jpg
ТОЛЬКО БАГ - сверху бордер исчезает ПРИ СКРОЛЕ масштаба